# How to restrict user access to files in git team devolopment system?

Tags: git, file-permissions

My team is working on a project using git system. But I want to restrict each user to access certain files only.
What I do know is that in git system every user have its own full version of all files and folders of project.It means if one member of my team go out, he can steal and start the full project.

I want to prevent each user to access all files but only files or folders I permit.
Is it an online service or windows software?
how can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have separate repositories, or is everything one large code base? You can allow or deny access to any repository by user.

Comment: @hunch_hunch Project is in php language and use mvc structure. Probably can split to repositories.

Answer (score 4):

There are two issues:

1. The technical issue. If you have the requirement you state, you either have to split the project into several git repositories and limit your developers' access to them or move away from a decentralized repository entirely. That every user has a complete copy of the repository is the very definition of a distributed version control system. If you can split the project and you host the repositories yourself, gitolite is a very easy way to accomplish that.
2. The trust issue. (Not going into details however, this is not the scope of this site. IMHO it's the far bigger issue though.)